# 'Power Nap' in ubuntu as in macbooks

Tags: 12.10, powernap

There is a 'power- nap' feature on new mackbooks which keeps all the activity going even when the lid is closed.(eg. downloading email,backing up,syncing)
Is there any such feature on ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup.  You can tell it to take no action when the lid is closed (Settings > Power).  That's as close as you'll get to a "power nap" either on Ubuntu or Windows - the power savings of a "power nap" are negligible at best.

Other than that (really just leaving your laptop on), there's nothing you can do as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Install TLP and configure your screen to turn off in lowest possible interval, you will get similar savings.